# Equation - Defining boundaries

Tags: equations

What is a better way or method to define region boundaries. For example, the following piece of code.

```
\begin{align}
&2 \pi  R\left[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\right].&\text{  for,  } \left[p\leq Q_0\right]\\
&0.\text{ }&\text{  for,  } \left[p>Q_0\right]
\end{align}
```

That gives an output of :

[image: Out]

Is there a better way to represent such boundary equations or this is the right way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a better spacing. A tricky solution in the first version. For some reasons the other versions might be more suitable for you, however I doubt. In all variants punctuation and spacing improved.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
2 \pi  R\left[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\right],&\quad\text{for  } \left[p\leq Q_0\right],\\
0,\hphantom{\pi  R\left[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\right]}&\quad\text{for  } \left[p>Q_0\right].
% tricky: 0, and 2, have the same length
\end{align}

\begin{align}
2 \pi  R\left[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\right],&\quad\text{for  } \left[p\leq Q_0\right],\\
0,&\quad\text{for  } \left[p>Q_0\right].
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&2 \pi  R\left[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\right],\quad\text{for  } \left[p\leq Q_0\right],\\
&0,\text{}\quad\text{for } \left[p>Q_0\right].
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems the boundary condition is dependent on `p`, perhaps a `numcases` (from the [`cases` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cases)) is okay. In the example below I define the boundary `B(p)` as a function of `p`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cases}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,cases}
\begin{document}
Some text here.
\begin{numcases}{B(p)=}
  2 \pi R\bigl[q_x-p_x,q_y-p_y\bigr] & \text{for $\bigl[p \leq Q_0\bigr]$} \\
  0 & \text{for $\bigl[ p > Q_0 \bigr]$}
\end{numcases}
Some more text here.
\end{document}
```

Most notably, the use of `\left`...`\right` in your code snippet is not necessary. Perhaps, as a means of emphasis (although not needed), I've used the `\bigl`...`\bigr` pairs.